# Jquery Click need two tap on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Jquery hover and click on mobile.. Let me explain!

I have square div and, when the mouse is hover it, a new div appear and follow the mouse. You can even click the square div and if so, a new page is opened. The problem now is that, on mobile, I need two click for the new page to be opened, since the first click is read as "hover".

I tried the

```
$("#mydiv").on('click touchend', function(e)
```

Actually it works, but with this, if I want to scroll the page on mobile, and I start the swipe on the square div, the new page is opened, which it shouldn't since I didn't click on the square div, just "passed by".

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of those events

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events#4-the-events

```
 $('#mydiv').bind('tap', function(e) { 
    console.log('User tapped #myDiv'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

"The event's target is the same element that received the touchstart event corresponding to the touch point, even if the touch point has moved outside that element."

You can see the documentation of touchend also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

If you start your scroll with the square div then square div touchend event will be fired after the release of that finger even after you move your finger to the other elements.

To solve this problem, you can use these events:

https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events#4-the-events

If you want to stick with this touchend event then there is a workaround:
Declare a global variable i.e.

```
var isScroll = false, timer;
```

Apply touchmove eventhandler on document which will fired for touch devices only, this handler detect whether the document is getting scrolled if yes set the isScroll flag to true that will false after 500ms:

```
$(document).on("touchmove", function(e) {
   isScroll = true;
   if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(function() {
     isScroll = false;
   }, 800);
```

})

and insert if condition in your eventHandler:

```
$("#mydiv").on('click touchend', function(e) {
   if(!isScroll) {
   //insert your code here;
   }
}
```